# Issue on live site

Tags: html

i am written don't worry but in my live site the text is displaying â€™ why?
Even in local it showing properly but in live it is not working what is the reason please tell me.

Comment: Have you set the page encoding correctly?

Comment: This looks like a character encoding issue. Without more information, we can't suggest a fix.

Answer (score 2):

That is what the UTF-8 encoded character `’` (entity: `&rsquo;`) looks like when it is served with the wrong character encoding, specifically Western (Windows 1252).

You need to either make sure the webserver sends it with the correct encoding or [add the encoding to the html document](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations). If you are using html5 use this in your head tag:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

If you are stuck with html4:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```

Or, if you are serving valid XHML of any flavour, put this at the top of your document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```